# Offloaded app is not reinstalling

Tags: iphone, applications

i need help please..
Few days ago i offloaded an app and i tried to reinstall it again because i need the data on it. But it says that the app is no longer on the apple store! And it shows only one option.. it’s to delete the application.

But seriously i need the data on it and i dont know what I might do until I hear back from Apple support.

I have an iphone 7 and Icontacted the Apple services and they told me to search for the app developer because they cant do anything for this issue unless it’s released again on the Apple store.

I can’t find the app anymore, neither the developer. And i need the data :( the app is called “calculator+”. It’s for keeping photos, videos and documents secretly.

Could anyone help me with that please?

Comment: Unless you have an older version of iTunes that included app management that would allow you to restore the app from iTunes, that may be a problem. You could use an app like iExplore (or another iPhone backup tool) to see if you can get the data out of the backup.

Comment: Do you have Time Machine (or other) backups that may include the app as part of the backup? If so, then there are ways to get the app onto your iPhone. If not, than  Steve's suggestion may be your best bet.  The only other option would be if the app also synced data to iCloud or other online storage, or if it created a backup to your computer (but I'm guessing this is unlikely considering the nature of the app).

Comment: If your iOS version is between 11.0 and 11.1.2, you can jailbreak your iPhone and *probably* get your data with Filza (file explorer with root access), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and get the data from a backup or use it on an older device.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7798616)

> If the app was deleted from the App Store and you were restoring an iCloud backup, whatever you saw was a glitch and the app was not going to download no matter what you saw. If the app is no longer available, it can not download again from the App Store.
>
> When you restore an iCloud backup, the apps download from your purchases in iTunes, not from the iCloud back up itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I ended solving by going to reinstall from the storage management screen
go to: settings > general > iphone storage > (wait for it to load the details of the apps) see your app and click on it > (click) Reinstall app

this worked for me...